# Convert string number with format X XXX,XX to number

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I convert this string `3 849,59` into a readable number format?

The result would be `3849,59`

I've tried `REGEXP_REPLACE(x,' ','')` which is working with others string but doesn't seem to work with "number" string...

I'm wondering if is there something like `date_format` for numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: what is expected result? also give few more examples to better understand your case

Comment: what exactly data type of output you expect?

Comment: Data in this column will be cost data so float data I guess but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have spaces where commas expected and commas where dot expected

So try below

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(x, ' ',''), ',', '.') AS FLOAT64)
```

for example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '3 849,59' x
)
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(x, ' ',''), ',', '.') AS FLOAT64)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

returns

```
Row f0_  
1   3849.59
```

Comment: got the following error "Bad double value: 1\302\240641.26" what does it mean? Is this a specific issue with my data set?

Comment: this means that in your column there are many different formats presented  - not just `1 234.56` and obviously those other formats will not be cast'ed and rather giving you error

Comment: Yes I guess I need to review my data set and uniformize it... I guess that is why I'm stuck.